# Modifying grid textview item from another item of the same grid

Tags: android, arrays, gridview

I want to make like a radio button effect with some text views inside a grid, so when a textview is clicked the textview text changes but if you click the other textview the one clicked before gets blank again changing the text of the last item clicked.

```
private Hay_nohay_familia[] datos = new Hay_nohay_familia[]{
        new Hay_nohay_familia("HAY", ""),
        new Hay_nohay_familia("NO HAY",""), 
        new Hay_nohay_familia("FAMILIA", ""), 
        new Hay_nohay_familia("", "1"), 
        new Hay_nohay_familia("", "1"),
        new Hay_nohay_familia("", "1"),};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prueba);


        final GridView grid;


        final AdaptadorFecha adaptador2 =
                new AdaptadorFecha(this);                 

        grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.hay_nohay_familia);


        grid.setAdapter(adaptador2);

        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                TextView fecha = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.fecha));





             fecha.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").format(new Date()));


            }
        });

}



        class AdaptadorFecha extends ArrayAdapter<Hay_nohay_familia> {

            Activity context;


                AdaptadorFecha(Activity context) {
                    super(context, R.layout.grd_radio, datos);
                    this.context = context;
                }

                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grd_radio, null);

                TextView hay = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.hay_nohay_familia);
                hay.setText(datos[position].getDatos());

                TextView fecha = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
                fecha.setText(datos[position].getFecha());




                return(item);
            }


        }
```

problem is that i cant access to the other textviews texts from the onitemclick in order to set them blank again. I came up with some ideas like changing the array data dynamically and giving the date value i want to the clicked textview from the function called by my custom adapter after refreshing the adapter and getting all the others to default text, but i am new at this and i dont know how to modify that array either.

PD: Adding adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); inside the onitemclick doesnt work because it also cleans the textview i want to change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found the answer by my own after burning my head.

I used

```
grid.getChildAt(position)
```

to acces the other items views and then to their corresponding textviews